# How to attach a game object to the player when it collided by player?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in which my player is a UFO, and when the player collides with other game objects, I need the game objects to be attached or floated in the air below the player (UFO), like original UFO. I tried to attach them as a child, but it didn't worked.

I made one script as below:

```
if (coll) {
    distance = Vector2.Distance (this.transform.position, player.transform.position);

    if (distance < 2) {
        this.transform.parent = encaixe.transform;
        this.transform.localPosition = new Vector2 (0f, 1.2f);
        this.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
        encaixe.rigidbody2D.gravityScale=0;
    }
}
```

In using this script, the gameobject is attaching, but the player is not moving as like original. The game object is pulling down or up forcefully.

Please suggest to me how to do this.

Comment: Is the child object kinematic?  (FWIW, you may want to check out http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ .)

Comment: Yes. The child object is a kinematic one. Both parent and child are having 2d rigidbodies.

Comment: What exactly is "encaixe"?

Comment: Oh sorry it is my object name. A simple bottle.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this Thread is rather old, but maybe someone might come across this question and is in need of an answer.

You can actively set the Object's Position and Rotation to the UFO's on Collision.
Something like the following (pseudocode):

```
private bool hasCollided = false;
void OnCollisionEnter()
{
  hasCollided = true;
}
void LateUpdate()
{
  if (hasCollided)
  {
    followPlayer();
  }
}
void followPlayer()
{
  //update position and rotation
}
```